# Sort based on a value in struct array c#

Tags: c#, arrays

I have an array of a struct which have a data item called total. I want to sort this array based on integer dataitem 'total'.

```
 struct Disease
{

    public int male; 
    public int female;
    public int total=0;
    public string diseaseName;

}
 Disease [] opDisease = new Disease [21];
 opDisease[0].total= somevalue1;
 opDisease[1].total= somevalue2;
            ...
            ...
            ...
            ...


 I want to sort opDisease array based on the value of 'total'.

 thank you!
```

Comment: .... what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to sort the original array, `Array.Sort` is more appropriate/efficient:

```
Array.Sort(opDisease, (d1, d2) => d1.total.CompareTo(d2.total));
```

If you want to sort descending you just have to reverse the condition, so:

```
Array.Sort(opDisease, (d1, d2) => d2.total.CompareTo(d1.total));
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var sortedDiseases = opDisease.OrderBy(d=>d.total);
```

or

```
var sortedDiseases = opDisease.OrderBy(d=>d.total).ToArray();
```

if you're planning to iterate over those sorted items more than once - it'll create a new array of `Disease` references.

Comment: Thank you and How can I access the variable sortedDiseases?

Comment: What do you mean? `sortedDiseases` is a new array (in second case), so you can use it the same way as `opDisease`, like `sortedDiseases[1].total = 10`.